# .htaccess 500 error after login with AuthType Basic

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "LOG IN"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

After logging in, I get a 500 error. If I clear the .htaccess file, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: does the .htpasswd file exist?

Comment: if not, here is a fast way to create: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Comment: Yes, it exists. I did actually use that to create the file.

Comment: Take a look in the error logs

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you have to write the full path to your .htpasswd (on linux: /path/to/.htpasswd)

From http://weavervsworld.com/docs/other/passprotect.html

> Troubleshooting
>
> Make sure that the path specified in AuthUserFile is the correct full
> path. This is a major cause of problems. If Apache cannot find the
> .htpasswd file, then all attempts will fail.
>
> Make sure the permissions
> on the .htaccess and .htpasswd files are set so that Apache can read
> them. chmod 0644 .htaccess chmod 0644 .htpasswd
>
> Other issues may be
> out of your control. Web administrators can lock down Apache so that
> it ignores all .htaccess files it encounters. This can be achieved
> with an AllowOverride None directive and option on the
> ServerRoot/DocumentRoot directories. If this is the case (.htaccess
> not allowed) you will have to kindly ask your web administrator to
> allow .htaccess files with authorization directives in your personal
> web directory. This can be achieved with AllowOverride AuthConfig
> directive and option.

Comment: What was the fix? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Guyver see my suggestion , it will surely clear your doubts.

Comment: Also: if you get the 500 only after logging in: check the permissions of the directory containing your htpasswd, Apache must be able to read and execute it. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question scores high in Google, I thought I'd append steven's answer a bit:

Full path to .htpasswd here refers to the real full path, not the path you see via ftp. For example, when I login to my shared hosting account with ftp, it seems my web root lives in /public_html

However that's just because how the ftp server is set up. The actual path to my web root is /home/username/public_html and setting the AuthUserFile keeping that in mind resolved the issue, at least for me.

I found the missing piece of information on the [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11748/htaccess-password-protection-generates-500-internal-server-error) site after some more googling.

Comment: Great addition, thanks! And let me add that the path can be found using `echo realpath(".");` via php.

Answer (score 3):

> Important : Full path to .htpasswd refers to the real full path if you are using terminal than use

```
maddy@maddy:/var/www/html/project_name$ pwd
/var/www/html/project_name
```

File In /var/www/html/project_name/**.htaccess**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/project_name/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

File In /var/www/html/project_name/**.htpasswd**

```
someuser:$apr1$oi0zg2sf$jTagKK2S7StjC0WSVJLUH0
```

To generate **user: password** combination refer

1) http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/
2) https://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator

Not tested

https://www.gaslampmedia.com/generate-htaccess-password-htpasswd-from-the-command-line/

Answer (score 1):

If you use php and get Error - 500

A good shot is:
create a php file 'info.php' with content:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Enter in this url in your browser
In Apache Environment 
Look for DOCUMENT_ROOT

Get this content Ex: 'C:/wamp/www/'
And update your .htaccess:

```
AuthUserFile 'C:/wamp/www/.htpasswd'
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: The question contains **"After logging in"** and the answers are not for that case.

I've ran into the same issue:

- set up the authentication just as in the question
- open the site in a browser
- the login window pops up, I authenticate successfully
- all subsequent requests result in 500
- the access log shows the response was 500 but nothing in the error log

In this case the parent directory of the htpasswd file was not readable to the user running Apache. Apparently the first authentication is served using root credentials and subsequent ones (checking if the auth is still correct?) done by the user running Apache.